# Can anyone tell me what the basic icons in Umbraco mean?

Tags: .net, umbraco

I've been asked to find out what several of the default icons in Umbraco mean, and if their meaning is somehow connected to being unable to move a node from one folder to another. Is there a handy, dandy list glossary somewhere of what all of these mean? The Umbraco forums talk incessantly about custom icons, but no one explains what they mean. Sorry for the noob question; this is literally the first time I have ever seen Umbraco, and good info seems sparse.

Comment: Sure. The icons in question: http://i35.tinypic.com/53k3mf.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Icons can be customised in each installation however two of the icons in your image have markers on them that will display regardless of the underlying icon.

**Icon with Star**
This is a node that has changes since it was last published. The changes have yet to be published.

**Icon with Stop Sign**
This is a protected Folder, e.g. role based protection. So a user must be logged in to view the content in this node and it's children and belong to one of the permitted roles.

The icons with the dots and square brackets goes back to Umbraco v3 I think which is quite dated and I can't remember exactly what they were however I suspect they were representative of a media file.

Comment: If Your using Umbraco 4.5.1, protected nodes won't show the correct icon (it's a bug)